# Cmder with PowerShell in VSCode not registering keyboard shortcut

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, cmder

I was able to setup VSCode so that I use Cmder on top of powershell.exe.
I was hoping that this would allow me to use common keyboard shortcuts such as Ctrl+Backspace to remove words faster. Unfortunately, it only outputs '^W' each time I hit that shortcut. In the standard cmd.exe or Cmder outside of VSCode this shortcut works.

Any idea why that is? I was thinking that that I'm expecting form this might not even be something that's supposed to work.

Thanks!

Here're my settings for reference:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
    "-ExecutionPolicy",
    "Bypass",
    "-NoLogo",
    "-NoProfile",
    "-NoExit",
    "-Command",
    ". 'C:\\Users\\..\\..\\Apps\\cmder_mini\\vendor\\profile.ps1'"
],
```

[image]